# Request in Download Manager getting automatically stopped and starting again after some time(2-3 mins)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-download-manager, android-background

I have a list of PDFs that I need to download in one click. For this I am using service to do the download Process. As this list is of big size, I am sending data in batches of 6 and when all PDFs in this batch gets downloaded another batch start to download.
In Service I am enqueuing the request in the batch of 6 in Download Manager to do the download process.

Now, we want to implement in a way that when some of the file is downloaded the user can open the downloaded PDF from the list (while others in the queue are downloading).
The problem I am facing -

1 - The screen getting stuck and we are able to open PDF in 2-3 clicks.

2 - Downloading getting stopped automatically and then again it start automatically after 1-2 mins

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if(intent != null){
       
        HashMap<Integer, DocumentJsonModel.Document> toDownloadList = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap = toDownloadList;
        ArrayList<DocumentJsonModel.Document> list;

        isFromFragment = intent.getBooleanExtra("isFromFragment", true);
        if(isFromFragment){
            list = new ArrayList<>(DocumentHelper.getInstance(this).getDocumentHashmap().values());
        }
        else{
            list = new ArrayList<>(DocumentHelper.getInstance(this).getDocumentsOfParticularGroup().getValues());
        }


        positionList = new ArrayList<>(hashMap.keySet());
        documentList = new ArrayList<>(hashMap.values());

        DownloadAllExecutor downloadAllExecutor = new DownloadAllExecutor();
        downloadAllExecutor.doInBackground();

    }

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

 
 private class DownloadAllExecutor extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...voids) {
        sendBatchToDownload(hashMap);
        return null;
    }
}

  private  void sendBatchToDownload(HashMap<Integer, DocumentJsonModel.Document> map){
    if(map.size() - downloadCount <= 7){ //Change for batch size
        if(positionList.size()>downloadCount) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (positionList.size() - downloadCount); i++) {
                initiateDownload(documentList.get(i + itemSentCount), positionList.get(i + itemSentCount), map.size());
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++){ //change for batch size
            initiateDownload(documentList.get(i+itemSentCount), positionList.get(i+itemSentCount), map.size());
        }
        itemSentCount+=7;
        //change for batch size
    }

}
```

Downloading File Code -

```
 @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
 public long downloadFile(String docId, String docFile, String docName, String description, String position, boolean isJustView, int listSize) {
    long downloadReference = 0;
    String root = "/twoway/saved_documents/";
    String BASE_DIR = getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath();

    File dir = new File(BASE_DIR + root);
    File file = new File(dir, docId + "_" + docFile);
    Log.d("DownloadTask", "inside downloadFile: - - - - - ");
    if(!isCancelledButtonPressed) {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            String fileUrl = DOCUMENT_URL + docFile;
            fileUrl = fileUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

            Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(fileUrl);
            //Create request for android download manager
            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(fileUri);
            //set title for download
            request.setTitle(docName);
            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
            //request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_ONLY_COMPLETION);
            //Setting description of request
            request.setDescription(description);

            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, null, "/twoway/saved_documents/"
                    + docId + "_" + docFile);

            //Enqueue download and save into referenceId
            downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: `downloadAllExecutor.doInBackground();` One does not call doInBackground() self. Remove that statement. doInBackground will be called automatically.

Comment: Replace with downloadAllExecuter.execute().

Comment: Terrible that you called your async task class an executor. Very confusing.